# Bootstrap datetimepicker showing inconsistency while used in bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

As the title suggests, the bootstrap datetimepicker is populated inside for modal for requirement. But, I see a lot of inconsistency from the datepicker as it sometimes pops up and sometimes it doesn't. I'm not understanding as to what exactly is happening as the console too doesn't show up anything when it doesn't pop up post a mouse click.

Here is modal code I'm using:

```
<div class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="top:50px;width:1150px">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close"
                    ng-click="close(false)" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                &times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><b>{{'Vacation Setting'}}</b></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="display:block;overflow:auto;min-height:340px">
            <!--<canvas id="processViewCanvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table class="table table-striped" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                        <tr>                             
                            <th style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; width: 200px;">FromDate</th>
                            <th style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; width: 200px;">ToDate</th>                               
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <th style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black; padding:5px;">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepickerfromDate'>
                                        <input id="fdata" type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="object.fdate" /> <!-- is-open="datePickerOne.opened" -->
                                        <span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="openStartDatePicker($event)">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black; padding:5px;">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepickertoDate'>
                                        <input id="tdata" type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="object.tdate" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </th>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="row" style="margin-top:40px;margin-left:40px;">
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top:5px;padding-left:10px; margin-top:5px;">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary ebs-btn" type="button" ng-click="btnExecute()" ng-disabled="exceptionChk">
                        Submit&nbsp;
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>-->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary ebs-btn" type="button" ng-click="btnExecute()" ng-disabled="exceptionChk">
                Submit&nbsp;
            </button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="close(true)" class="btn btn-primary ebs-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the script in the same file for e.g purposes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepickerfromDate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'

        });
        $('#datetimepickertoDate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            minDate: 'now'
        });
        $("#datetimepickerfromDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            var presentDate = new Date();
            var dateSelected = e.date;
            if (dateSelected > presentDate) {
                $('#datetimepickertoDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
            }
            else {
                //presentDate.setDate(presentDate.getDate() - 1);
                $('#datetimepickertoDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment().millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0));
            }
        });
        $("#datetimepickertoDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepickerfromDate').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);

        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the master file by the scripts files are loading when the application is accessed:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/font-awesome.min.css">    <
<link href="Content/angular-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/tabdrop/tabdrop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/bootstrapdatetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/spin.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jsonpath.js"></script>   
<script src="Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment-duration-format.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/underscore.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Chartjs_Stacked.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-modal-service.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>   
<script src="Scripts/tabdrop/bootstrap-tabdrop.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ba-hashchange.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrapdatetimepicker.js"></script>
```

Is there some order I'm missing when I trying to load up all these scripts and link files as I know it might one of the reasons. Although, I do know that the calendar will not work at all if the order is disturbed.

I'm seriously confused. Please help me out here

Update:

I narrowed it down with my research that Angular Modal Service is what that might be conflicting with the datepicker, but, still not able to resolve.

This is my Modal Service:

```
   ModalService.showModal({
                templateUrl: "views/Reassign/VacationSetting.html",
                controller: "VacController",
                inputs: {
                    modalData: {}
                }
            }).then(function (modal) {
                // The modal object has the element built, if this is a bootstrap modal
                // you can call 'modal' to show it, if it's a custom modal just show or hide
                // it as you need to.
                modal.element.modal();
                modal.close.then(function (result) {
                    return result;
                });
            });
```

Could anyone see anything that I'm missing out?
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2307
This is EXACTLY that's happening to me. Tried applying whatever was told in that link but to no avail. 
Cheers

Comment: People. Any ideas? I'm still struck

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

This solve your case.

```
$scope.$apply(function(){

  ModalService.showModal({
                templateUrl: "views/Reassign/VacationSetting.html",
                controller: "VacController",
                inputs: {
                    modalData: {}
                }
            }).then(function (modal) {
                // The modal object has the element built, if this is a bootstrap modal
                // you can call 'modal' to show it, if it's a custom modal just show or hide
                // it as you need to.
                modal.element.modal();
                modal.close.then(function (result) {
                    return result;
                });
            });
}
```

## And in VacController

```
angular.module('app').controller('VacController',
['$scope','close','$timeout','safeApply',
function ($scope,close,$timeout,safeApply) {
    $scope.dt = {};

safeApply($scope, function() {  
    //$scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', 
     $scope.$watch('dt.value',
            function() { 
                $timeout(function() {


        $('#datetimepickerfromDate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'

        });
        $('#datetimepickertoDate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            minDate: 'now'
        });
        $("#datetimepickerfromDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            var presentDate = new Date();
            var dateSelected = e.date;
            if (dateSelected > presentDate) {
                $('#datetimepickertoDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
            }
            else {
                //presentDate.setDate(presentDate.getDate() - 1);
                $('#datetimepickertoDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment().millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0));
            }
        });
        $("#datetimepickertoDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepickerfromDate').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);

  },0);    
        });
    });

    }]);
```

## in your modaltemplate.html

```
.......................
<div class="modal-body">
    //ADD dt.value to enclose <div id='datepicker'> 
          <div ng-model="dt.value">
                <div id='datepicker'></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Example]

```
.dropdown-menu {
    font-family: Segoe UI Emoji;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    max-height: 230px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    z-index: 1050;
}
```